# Return content that is connected to all, not any, of the specified nodes (Cypher/Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to return content nodes based on terms that the user has selected. The following is my cypher query as it is:

```
    MATCH 
        (content:content)-[:TAGGED_WITH]-(term:term)
    WHERE
        term.UUID IN {includedTerms}
        AND NOT term.UUID IN {excludedTerms}
    RETURN DISTINCT content.whatever
```

Where `{includedTerms}` is an array of UUIDs for the terms to be included.

The problem is that it is returning content connected to any of the included term nodes rather than content that is connected to each of the included term nodes.

I realize that the query is returning exactly what I'm telling it to. The question is how can I specify that the content must be tagged with every (and not any) of the term nodes that the user has selected?

Thanks a lot- let me know if there is any needed clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using WITH could help:

```
MATCH 
    (content:content)-[:TAGGED_WITH]-(term:term)
WHERE
    term.UUID IN {includedTerms}
    AND NOT term.UUID IN {excludedTerms}
WITH content, count(*) as connectedTerms
WHERE connectedTerms = {_included_terms_size_}
RETURN DISTINCT content.whatever
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm not understanding why. What are count(*) and the second WHERE clause doing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: count is like a group by in sql: you'll have the content and the count will be the number of terms it is connected with. The second where clause is just checking that the numbers of connected terms is what you expect

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand the use of `NOT term.UUID IN {excludedTerms}` but you can edit below query as per your needs.

The below query will use only the `term` nodes which will have `UUIDs` attributes from the desired `includedTerms` set.

```
MATCH (term:term) 
WHERE term.UUID IN [includedTerms] 
WITH collect(term) AS ms 
MATCH (content:content)-[r:TAGGED_WITH]->(x) 
WHERE x IN ms 
WITH content, count(r) AS rs,ms 
WITH collect(content) AS ns, collect(rs) AS rss, length(ms) AS mss 
RETURN [t IN range(0,length(ns)-1) 
  WHERE rss[t]=mss | ns[t]] AS result
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, after testing, it seems this solution does not solve the problem. With this query I'm still getting content that is connected to any of the included terms rather than all of them, just as before.

Comment: can you share a graph gist or sample dataset?

Comment: Also, the intention of the NOT part of the query is to indicate that content connected to those terms should not be returned.

Comment: [Here is a link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_P0cOdXEB3damFMNExFUWdPOWM&usp=sharing) to a sample data set via google drive. I've never made a graph gist before but can look into it.